# Left Join en consulta Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Buen día!

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT CLIENTE.CTE, 
            CLIENTE.NO_EMPLEADO, 
            CLIENTE.CTE_N, 
            CLIENTE.NOMBRE, 
            CLIENTE.AP_PATERNO, 
            CLIENTE.AP_MATERNO, 
            CLIENTE.INGRESO, 
            CLIENTE.UNIDAD,
            CLIENTE.ACOMULADO, 
            CLIENTE.PERNO, 
            CLIENTE.FIAR, 
            CLIENTE.FIARN 
        FROM 
            ESQUEMA.CLIENTES CLIENTE 
        WHERE CLIENTE.CTE = '25') 
    TABLA01 
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
            SOLI.CTE, 
            SOLI.CONTROL, 
            SOLI.EST, 
            SOLI.MUN, 
            SOLI.LUG 
        FROM 
            ESQUEMA.DATOS SOLI 
        WHERE 
            SOLI.CTE = '25')
    TABLA2 ON TABLA1.CTE = TABLA2.CTE;
```

La cual trabaja muy bien, un query directo sin problemas, pero hace poco se implemento el no tener querys directos sino en puro SP, pero para sorpresa mía no se permite el select* en un SP(reglas de donde trabajo), entonces intente cambiar mi query quitando el '*':

```
SELECT 
    CLIENTE.CTE, 
    CLIENTE.NO_EMPLEADO, 
    CLIENTE.CTE_N, 
    CLIENTE.NOMBRE, 
    CLIENTE.AP_PATERNO, 
    CLIENTE.AP_MATERNO, 
    CLIENTE.INGRESO, 
    CLIENTE.UNIDAD,
    CLIENTE.ACOMULADO, 
    CLIENTE.PERNO, 
    CLIENTE.FIAR, 
    CLIENTE.FIARN 
FROM 
    ESQUEMA.CLIENTES CLIENTE 
WHERE 
    CLIENTE.CTE = '25' 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        SOLI.CTE, 
        SOLI.CONTROL, 
        SOLI.EST, 
        SOLI.MUN, 
        SOLI.LUG 
    FROM 
        ESQUEMA.DATOS SOLI 
    WHERE SOLI.CTE = '25')
TABLA2 ON CLIENTE.CTE=TABLA2.CTE;
```

Pero no me funciona, dado que me trae más de un dato( 2... rows), cuando con el primero solo obtengo un solo resultado (1 row).

Tengo entendido que un left join traerá los datos que coincidan con lo que se busca en la izquierda, mi pregunta es, cómo podría reestructurar mi query para no hacer uso del 'select*'?

Gracias.

Comment: Intenta mover tu `WHERE` después del `LEFT JOIN` dado que normalmente ese es el orden correcto en como deben de ir las sentencias SQL.

Comment: Estás seguro que esos son los códigos exactos que estás usando?. El segundo no parece válido. Y aún si lo fuera, se puede ver que no es equivalente al primero

Comment: @Lixus lo intentaré como dices

Comment: @Lamak si son esos, lo que intento es quitar mi primer SELECT *FROM()... por campos en concreto, como lo dije, no puedo poner en producción un SP con ese tipo de consulta.

Comment: pero no necesitas quitar el `SELECT * FROM()`, simplemente reemplazar `*` por los nombres de las columnas: `SELECT CTE, NO_EMPLEADO, CTE_N,..... FROM()`

Comment: @Lamak pero al hacerlo de esa forma los campos que se requieren de la segunda tabla no son obtenidos, según recuerdo el left join, en caso de que no haya coincidencias sobre la segunda tabla, estos regresan un valor nulo y al hacerlo como tu lo indicas esos campos no aparecen en el resultado.

Comment: las dos consultas no son iguales y ese es el problema...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esta consulta, ya que las dos consultas que estas mostrando no son iguales:

```
SELECT 
    TABLA01.CTE, 
    TABLA01.NO_EMPLEADO, 
    TABLA01.CTE_N, 
    TABLA01.NOMBRE, 
    TABLA01.AP_PATERNO, 
    TABLA01.AP_MATERNO, 
    TABLA01.INGRESO, 
    TABLA01.UNIDAD,
    TABLA01.ACOMULADO, 
    TABLA01.PERNO, 
    TABLA01.FIAR, 
    TABLA01.FIARN,
    TABLA2.CTE, 
    TABLA2.CONTROL, 
    TABLA2.EST, 
    TABLA2.MUN, 
    TABLA2.LUG 
FROM
    (SELECT CLIENTE.CTE, 
            CLIENTE.NO_EMPLEADO, 
            CLIENTE.CTE_N, 
            CLIENTE.NOMBRE, 
            CLIENTE.AP_PATERNO, 
            CLIENTE.AP_MATERNO, 
            CLIENTE.INGRESO, 
            CLIENTE.UNIDAD,
            CLIENTE.ACOMULADO, 
            CLIENTE.PERNO, 
            CLIENTE.FIAR, 
            CLIENTE.FIARN 
        FROM 
            ESQUEMA.CLIENTES CLIENTE 
        WHERE CLIENTE.CTE = '25') 
    TABLA01 
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
            SOLI.CTE, 
            SOLI.CONTROL, 
            SOLI.EST, 
            SOLI.MUN, 
            SOLI.LUG 
        FROM 
            ESQUEMA.DATOS SOLI 
        WHERE 
            SOLI.CTE = '25')
    TABLA2 ON TABLA1.CTE = TABLA2.CTE;
```

Fijate que lo unico que hice fue agregar los campos que querias en el primer select.

Comment: Eso era lo que quería decir en mi comentario. Esta es la respuesta correcta.

Comment: @Gbianchi gracias , era agregar los campos de la tabla2 en mi pirmer select.